# Can we trigger Chrome Extension using jquery or php

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Can we trigger Chrome Extension using jquery or PHP?

there is one extension Full Page Screen Capture for capturing the whole page, which can be triggered by a keyboard event:-

Alt+shift+P

I tried triggering alt+shift+p by using below code but not working

Link for Extention:- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl

```
setTimeout(function(){
    e.altKey = true;
    e.shiftKey = true;
    e.keyCode = e.which = 80; // 'P' key code value
    console.log(e);            
    $(document).trigger(e);
}, 2000);
```

I need the whole page screenshot like this extension.

Comment: Can't be PHP, that's server-side scripting only. No idea if this can be done with javascript/jquery.

Comment: If the extension uses [commands API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands), you can't trigger it from within a web page, but only using an external utility that emits system-level keyboard events (like AutoHotkey in Windows). The only case where you can succeed is when the extension uses a content script with a standard `keydown` listener to listen to hotkeys.

Comment: @wOxxOm, extension link has been attached

Comment: It uses the Commands API as you can see in its manifest.json.

Comment: I know nothing about Chrome extensions, but can it be done by setting a cookie or another such header?

Comment: @benJ Thanks, can you please provide some example, that will be much appreciated.